# Seeking not allowed on media in blackberry video player

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created a video player which retrieves data from the server and plays.
The content type is Video/mp4.  When I try to rewind the video I get `ERROR:Seeking not allowed on media`

Per the API documentation, setMediaTime(int) does not support certain media types. What media types does the player support and is there any work around to rewind the video?

```
rewind() {
   _player.setMediaTime(0);
   _player.start();
}
```